# How do I send a tweet using OAuth 2.0 Client ID and Client Secret?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

I am interested in sending a tweet using Python. I was told that I need to use OAuth 2 to do that but I am not sure where to get started. I have changed my settings to 'read and write', and I got assigned Client ID and Secret ID credentials but I am unsure what to do with them. For Callback URL I put http://localhost.

I found the below code but it does not seem to utilize Client ID or Secret ID. And with this code I get an error, Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 Application-Only is forbidden for this endpoint.  Supported authentication types are [OAuth 1.0a User Context, OAuth 2.0 User Context].

```
import tweepy
client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key="",
                    consumer_secret="",
                    access_token="",
                    access_token_secret="")
# Replace the text with whatever you want to Tweet about
response = client.create_tweet(text='test',  user_auth=False)
```

I would appreciate any help! Thanks.